# Where is the code that receives blocks that miners have just solved

Tags: client, block, bitcoin-core-development, relay

I was just looking through the Bitcoin code but since I am relatively new to C++ I was wondering, if anybody could tell me where the code responsible for receiving blocks that have just been mined by someone else is located.

My understanding is that when a miner successfully solves a block, it is broadcasted to the entire system. What I am looking for is the code responsible for how that broadcast is intercepted by other nodes if that makes more sense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Look in `main.cpp` at the `ProcessBlock` function. The meat is in the `AcceptBlock` function in the same file.